# Nested List in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I have two models, something like this:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    text = models.TextField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Please tell me, is it possible to display these models in the standard Django admin panel like this:

[image]

perhaps there is some extension to implement verbose output?

Comment: This Package Might help. [Django-mppt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)